# hybris cannot find my item type but it does exist

Tags: types, sap-commerce-cloud

When starting up my hybris server I get the following message on my console:

```
ERROR [WrapperSimpleAppMain] (junit) [DefaultModelConverterRegistry] code PedraProduct does not belong to known type. Maybe you have added a new type without updating your system.
```

But I have updated my system and I CAN find my item type on the hMC. If I open my hMC, go to System > Types and search for my type **PedraProduct** there, hybris finds it.

So why do get this error message and how do I fix it?

Comment: Why I you so worry about this error message? Is there any problems with it in your app?

Comment: Probably you need to use the generated type in your converter, i.e. PedraProductModel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've updated the master tenant i would bet, but have you updated the junit tenant? You can do this via the ant system or via the hac.

Try using the hac to switch the current tenant then using the update running system. If this hasn't worked for you, then do a full init in the junit tenant.